# how to update h:panelGroup using f:ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to update h:panelGroup using f:ajax.When, i select h:selectBooleanCheckbox getting value from officeAdd1 and set this value into headOfficeAdd1.Am getting officeAdd1 value in bean but i want to update value into headOfficeAdd1.

Thanks...

```
      <h:form id="form">
   <p:panel id="display">            
                <p:spacer width="20" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="6">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Address:"
                        style="text-align: left;display: block;width:130px;" />
                    <p:inputTextarea
                        value="#{companyInformationBean.current.officeAdd1}"
                        autoResize="true" style="width:170px;" maxlength="150" />

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="6">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="remember"
                        value="#{companyInformationBean.current.checkBox}">
                        <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"
                            listener="#{companyInformationBean.checkBoxValue}" />
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Same as Registered Office Address"
                        style="text-align: left;display: block;" />
                    <p:spacer width="20" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:spacer width="20" />
                <h:panelGroup id="hidepanelgroup">
                <h:panelGrid id="getaddress" columns="6">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Head Office Address:"
                        style="text-align: left;display: block;width:130px;" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="headadd"
                        value="#{companyInformationBean.current.headOfficeAdd1}"
                        autoResize="true" style="width:170px;" maxlength="150" />

               </h:panelGrid>
               </h:panelGroup>
   </p:panel> 
   </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
      public void checkBoxValue()
{
    if(current.getCheckBox()==true)
    {

            logger.info("getofadd"+current.getOfficeAdd1());
            current.setHeadOfficeAdd1(current.getOfficeAdd1());

    }
    else
    {
            logger.info("checkbox value false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your misusing it. Input text area value is set in `#{companyInformationBean.current.headOfficeAdd1}` when the form is sent, you don't have to explicitly set it using the setter method, JSF does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify client IDs-to-render in the `<f:ajax render>` attribute.

Thus, given that the second textarea has an ID of `headadd`, this should do:

```
<f:ajax ... render="headadd" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, comparing booleans against booleans in a boolean expression really doesn't make any sense. Just check the boolean itself directly.

```
if (current.getCheckBox())
```

By the way, try to use self-documenting property and method names. A property name of `remember` would be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks BalusC it works.But,i ask one more question it is possible to render more than one field.If i render more than one field it shows error like UI Layout Initialization error.

Comment: Yes, you can specify client IDs spaceseparated in `render` attribute like so `render="headadd anotherId"`.

Comment: Change `event="change"` back to `event="click"` or just remove it altogether. The default for checkboxes is `click`. As to the concrete problem of "whole form get disabled", this isn't clear. You'd better ask a new question on this with code in SSCCE flavor.

Comment: I want to renderd 5 fields at a time <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="headadd headcity headpincode headstate headcountry" listener="#{companyBean.checkBoxValue}" />.
But,when I select booleancheckbox whole form get disabled.I don't know what mistake i have done.