# How to update a panel group using ajax in a different view scope on p:commandButton click in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, view

I need to know how to update a panel group using ajax which is in different view state of JSF application in same page on clicking a primefaces commandbutton in the view.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, you just want push?

Comment: @BalusC Yes.. I m trying it out. Facing challenges because of this

Comment: You'll have more chance on success if you ask about the individual "challenge" instead of asking an overly generic question. We can right now basically only "answer" that PrimeFaces has a <p:socket> for the specific purpose, which you probably already know for long if you've already checked its documentation/showcase. In other words, this question isn't terribly useful for anyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update h:panelGroup using f:ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200506/how-to-update-hpanelgroup-using-fajax)

Comment: @Risadinha: Don't think it is...

Comment: I solved the issue by using a session scoped managed bean..

Thank U all for ur support